# Do I need to reprogram the default WordPress navigation menu or is it intuitive as is?

Tags: wordpress, menu, navigation

## The problem

The default navigation menu for WordPress consists of links to parent pages and a sub-menu that drops down for the respective child pages. It's been pointed out to me that it's not obvious that the primary (parent) links are selectable i.e. when the drop down child page links appear the user apparently might disregard the primary link to the corresponding parent page.

## An example

Have a peek at the main navigation menu on this website:

http://www.directsponsor.org/forums/

## My question

In my mind, the default WordPress navigation menu set-up is semantic, intuitive and best practice. To the non-technically inclined mind, is the menu intuitive enough? i.e. will all users observe the parent link or do I need to reprogram the menu?

## Potential solutions

1. It's been suggested to me that I reiterate the parent links in the drop down menu. This seems like terribly bad practice and breaks the overall semantics of the menu. It's my opinion that the selectivity of the parent page links are already implied by the hover state.
2. Using CSS to more obviously imply the selectivity of the parent page links.
3. Reprogram the menu altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Check 'Menu Manager' Plugin in WP which provides features of dynamic menu creation.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that the menu is generated by the Thematic framework. Either way, did you actually read my question? I provided a link with a working example. I just need to know whether you feel it's intuitive or not.